# Removing Day and Time from Excel Dump

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I was given a data file with user data and one of the fields is formatted as a text field like so:

```
Thursday, November 30, 2019, 2:32 PM
```

I only need the date "November 30, 2019" but all I can find are "fixes" that tell me to just reformat the field to date. I found a formula that removed the day, but then I am still left with "November 30, 2019, 2: 32 PM" replacing the "," also removes the comma from the date which then does not allow me to use the Excel format field to DATE.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,999),",","",2)
```

Then format the output as desired.

[image]

the above retains the time portion.  If only the date is desired then use:

```
=INT(--SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,999),",","",2))
```

Comment: Simple, elegant, and absolutely what I needed! Thanks Scott!

Comment: please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would honestly stick with the reformatting myself. But the other alternative is to use the Text-to-Columns in the Data tab. It will allow you to split the text and delimit it by Commas. Then you would end up with 4 columns and you can then delete the one with the Day and the one with the time. The Text-To-Columns has a wizard that should be easy enough to navigate through and the Excel help is surprisingly useful in this case.